# Вывод текста определенного radio input

Tags: javascript, html, input

Есть блок с input как на картинке ниже. Оно нужно для выбора альбома, для последующей загрузки картинок в этот альбом. При выборе ( Нажатии на input radio ) выводиться текст описания альбома. 
Так вот, в добавленном коде, выводиться div как нужно, но с одним нюансом. При выборе, старые div-ы не закрываются. Нужно подправить имеющийся код так, чтобы при выборе альбома, старое описание закрывалось и новое появлялось. 
Понятно описал? 
В итоге, нужен код который закрывает div у того блока, у которого убирается checked.

---

**Пример:**

[image: Пример]

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    show("bloggood1", "cat1","$_GET[a]");
    });
      function show(bloggood, cat, id){
        bloggood = document.getElementById(bloggood);
        cat = document.getElementById(cat);
     albom = document.getElementById('albom_vibor');
        if (bloggood.checked){
      albom_vibor.value = id;
      cat.style.display = "block"; 
     }else{ 
      albom_vibor.value = '';
      cat.style.display = "none";
     };
      };
    </script>
```

```html
    <div class='addimage-albom-box'>
    <input type='radio' name='bloggood' class="radio" id="bloggood$albom[id]" onchange='show("bloggood$albom[id]","cat$albom[id]","$albom[id]");'/>
    <label for='bloggood$albom[id]'>$albom[title]</label>
    <div id='cat$albom[id]' class='addimage-albom-box-opisanie'>
$albom[opisanie]
     <small>Вы выбрали этот альбом. Теперь Вы можете загрузить картинку в него.</small>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: А что у вас не получилось? Можно увидеть вашу попытку что-то сделать? Или вам все с нуля сделать?

Comment: У меня на jsfiddle есть пример с инпутами checked, спокойно можно переделать под radio. Остальное делается очень просто, скрыть нужный div или показать его при активном инпуте

Comment: У меня показывает div в выбранном radio, но не убирает с других. if (bloggood.checked){cat.style.display = "block";} Делаю через присваивание css.

Comment: Ну что? Вопрос актуален, было бы круто, если бы Вы скинули готовый код своей версии...

Comment: @АльбертУшаков тут не делают задания за вас..... зато за вас сделают задание на фрилансе

Comment: @АльбертУшаков, добавь пример своего кода/разметки/css непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: Он с php если Вам это поможет. <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
show("bloggood1", "cat1","$_GET[a]");
});
  function show(bloggood, cat, id){
    bloggood = document.getElementById(bloggood);
    cat = document.getElementById(cat);
 albom = document.getElementById('albom_vibor');
    if (bloggood.checked){
  albom_vibor.value = id;
  cat.style.display = "block"; 
 }else{ 
  albom_vibor.value = '';
  cat.style.display = "none";
 };
  };
</script>

Comment: эта функция только а одном месте вызывается? нужно еще добавить пример разметки и описание что делает функция сейчас и что ожидается она должна делать

Comment: @Grundy Можете подсказать фрагментом только той части кода, в которой закрываются все остальные div-ы кроме той, что выбрана, то есть на том что checked.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков, не понял вопроса

Comment: @Grundy Можете написать фрагмент кода, который закрое все div кроме выбранного input radio?

Comment: Исправил код, добавил html и подробное описание того, что нужно.

Comment: Я бы добавил новую переменную, в которой бы, например, хранил id выбранного `input radio`, при каждом выборе сравнивал id, если они различаются, то закрыл бы альбом с id(из переменной) и переписал ее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    var thisDescription = $(this).parent().find('.addimage-albom-box-opisanie');
    thisDescription.slideDown();
    $('.addimage-albom-box-opisanie').not(thisDescription).slideUp();
});
```

```css
.addimage-albom-box-opisanie {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='addimage-albom-box'>
  <input type='radio' name='r' id="r1" />
  <label for='r1'>Radio 1</label>
  <div class='addimage-albom-box-opisanie'>
    <small>Вы выбрали этот альбом. Теперь Вы можете загрузить картинку в него.</small>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='addimage-albom-box'>
  <input type='radio' name='r' id="r2" />
  <label for='r1'>Radio 2</label>
  <div class='addimage-albom-box-opisanie'>
    <small>Вы выбрали этот альбом. Теперь Вы можете загрузить картинку в него.</small>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='addimage-albom-box'>
  <input type='radio' name='r' id="r3" />
  <label for='r1'>Radio 3</label>
  <div class='addimage-albom-box-opisanie'>
    <small>Вы выбрали этот альбом. Теперь Вы можете загрузить картинку в него.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

как-то так. либо js чистом либо с jquery.

```js
//$(".addimage-albom-box-opisanie").prop("hidden", true);

//$("[name=bloggood]").change(function(){
// var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
//  console.log(id);
//  $(".addimage-albom-box-opisanie").prop("hidden", true);
//  $("#" + id).prop("hidden", false);
//})
```

```css
.addimage-albom-box-opisanie {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function foo(item) {
    var id = item.getAttribute("data-id");
    console.log(id);
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("addimage-albom-box-opisanie");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (i == id - 1) {

        x[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  };




</script>

<div class='addimage-albom-box'>
  <input type='radio' name='bloggood' class="radio" id="radio1" data-id="1" onchange='foo(this);' />
  <label for='bloggood$albom[id]'>radio1</label>
  <div id='1' class='addimage-albom-box-opisanie'>
    <small>Вы выбрали этот альбом. Теперь Вы можете загрузить картинку в него.</small>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type='radio' name='bloggood' class="radio" id="radio2" data-id="2" onchange='foo(this);' />
  <label for='bloggood$albom[id]'>radio2</label>
  <div id='2' class='addimage-albom-box-opisanie'>
    <small>Вы выбрали этот альбом. Теперь Вы можете загрузить картинку в него.</small>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type='radio' name='bloggood' class="radio" id="radio3" data-id="3" onchange='foo(this);' />
  <label for='bloggood$albom[id]'>radio3</label>
  <div id='3' class='addimage-albom-box-opisanie'>
    <small>Вы выбрали этот альбом. Теперь Вы можете загрузить картинку в него.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь)